# Match url from .net-core web api with angular 11

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have the following .net-core controller:

```
using CadastroDerivativos.Domain.Entities.EquityOpt;
using CadastroDerivativos.Domain.Interfaces.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CadastroDerivativos.WebApiAngular.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EquityOptController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IEquityOptService _equityOptService;

        public EquityOptController(IEquityOptService equityOptService)
        {
            _equityOptService = equityOptService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<EquityOptions>> GetEquityOpt()
        {
            return Ok(_equityOptService.GetEquityOpts());
        }
    }
}
```

and the following angular component and interface:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

import { EquityOpt } from './equityopt';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-equityopt',
  templateUrl: './equityopt.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./equityopt.component.css']
})
export class EquityOptComponent {
  //public displayedColumns: string[] = ['Ticker', 'Instrument', 'Strike', 'Market',
  //                                     'Payout', 'Style', 'MaturityLabel']

  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['ticker', 'instrument']
  public equitiesOpts: MatTableDataSource<EquityOpt>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.getData(); 
    }

    getData(){
      var url = 'http://localhost:44369/api/equityopt';
      this.http.get<any>(url)
        .subscribe(result => {
          this.equitiesOpts = new MatTableDataSource<EquityOpt>(result.data);
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

export interface EquityOpt{
  ticker: string;
  instrument: string;
  maturityLabel: string;
  strike: number;
  payout: string;
  market: string;
  style: string;    
}
```

In `https://localhost:44369/api/equityopt` I can get the data from .net core:

```
[
  {
    "instrument": "EWZ",
    "maturityLabel": "MAI 20 D29",
    "strike": 28,
    "payout": "P",
    "style": "A",
    "maturity": "2020-05-29T00:00:00",
    "market": "US NYSE",
    "ticker": "EWZ US 05/29/20 P28"
  },
  {
    "instrument": "TLT",
    "maturityLabel": "JUN 20 D19",
    "strike": 226,
    "payout": "C",
    "style": "E",
    "maturity": "2020-06-19T00:00:00",
    "market": "HK HKSE",
    "ticker": "TLT US 06/19/20 C226"
  },
  {
    "instrument": null,
    "maturityLabel": "MAI 20 D29",
    "strike": 31,
    "payout": "P",
    "style": "A",
    "maturity": "2020-05-29T00:00:00",
    "market": "US NYSE",
    "ticker": "XLE US 05/29/20 P31"
  }
]
```

But I can't pass this data to the angular component, but in the url `http://localhost:4200/equityopt` I can access the component's front-end, as shown below:

[image]

So, my problem is precisely in the communication of the back with the front-end, where I make the data available in a different url than the front-end expects to receive. I have already looked at my settings several times and could not identify the error. I'm using angular 11 and .net core 3. Can anyone help? My startup class:

```
using CadastroDerivativos.Infra.IoC;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace CadastroDerivativos.WebApiAngular
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    // set this option to TRUE to indent the JSON output
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
                    // set this option to NULL to use PascalCase instead of CamelCase (default)
                    // options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                });


            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            DependencyInjectConfig.Register(services);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you click F12,can you see errors in your Console?

Comment: in the url (https://localhost:44369/api/equityopt) that the backend is running there is no error, it returns a json. now in the frontend url (http://localhost:4200/api/equityopt), I take this error Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. Segment URL: 'api / equityopt'. But, in this url, without 'api', (http://localhost:4200/equityopt) I can load the template.

Answer (score 0):

You did a http request in the component `http://localhost:44369/api/equityopt`, while the api accept a https request.

Comment: the same thing happens, regardless of the url I pass in getdata().